# JQuery autocomplete wont bind to elements in document.ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a series of text boxes that are generated server side. They have id's that end with a distinguishing number like so:

ictContractNumber_0, ictContractNumber_1, etc

When the page loads I want to make these textboxes autocomplete boxes so I'm using the following code inside the document ready:

```
$('[id^="ictContractNumber_"]').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
      GetContract(request.term, response);
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that it doesn't work when the page loads. All of my other code in the document ready works so I know it's being run, it just doesn't work.

The odd thing is that I can manually run this code in the Firebug console and then it works fine!

I'm stumped.

Comment: Any errors on the page.. If not try writing this in $(window).load() event instead of DOM ready handler

Comment: If this is the only code depending on jquery-ui, could you be loading this before loading the jquery-ui.js?

Comment: Sushanth - No errors. st3inn - there is other Jquery ui stuff that is running fine. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the starts-with syntax in the selector. I've found that if I manually select each textbox using it's full name, it works. (not a solution through since I won't know how many elements to select in production)

Comment: Can you reproduce in [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Added the solution. Classes work where the starts-with id selector did not, even though I verified that the right elements were being returned. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working. I don't think this is a real solution, but it's a workaround. I simply used classes instead of the id's to select the elements and that works. Here's the working code:

```
$('.ibaContractSearch').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    GetContract(request.term, response);
  }
});
```